# What is the reason for this code to be valid?

Tags: apex

Would you know the reason for this to be a valid Exception class?

It does compile, and it does work, but I wonder if it is an undocumented behaviour.

```
public class NoneDAGException extends Exception {

    {
        this.setMessage('Object graph should be a Directed Acyclic Graph.');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an initialization code, as mentioned in the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm):

> The instance initialization code in a class is executed each time an
> object is instantiated from that class. These code blocks run before
> the constructor.
>
> If you don’t want to write your own constructor for a class, you can
> use an instance initialization code block to initialize instance
> variables. In simple situations, use an ordinary initializer. Reserve
> initialization code for complex situations, such as initializing a
> static map. A static initialization block runs only one time,
> regardless of how many times you access the class that contains it.

Comment: Wow, something new I learned today. I've always just initialised static variables in place, didn't know this was possible. Neat.